# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector on boolean array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using `typedef` to define `set` as a `bool` array:

```
typedef struct set{
   bool Arr[128];
}set;
```

the problem is that every time I try to assign a t/f value, e.g.

```
temp[itemp]=true;
```

(`temp` is a `set` as defined and `itemp` is an `int`),
I get the error:

```
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

I have no idea how to fix this, please help.

PS :I'm using C on ubuntu.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And also copy-paste the actual errors into the body of the question, unedited and in full.

Comment: "*nor vector*" there are no vectors in C. So this error message had not been issued by a C compiler. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm assuming the only reason you're using a `struct` here rather than just `typedef bool set[128];` is because without one you can't pass a `set` by value across a function parameter list, nor can you direct-assign two `set` objects. Given those plausible reasons, I'm vexed how you seemingly missed the fact the member `Arr`has to play some sort of role in your assignment statement.

Comment: @alk Turns out gcc has a compiler extension for "vector" variables in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you've done is an alias called `set` to a struct containing an array of bools with the size of 128. This means, that to access the member `Arr`, you need to use the member access operator `.` like so:

```
temp.Arr[itemp] = true;
```

If you don't want to do that, you can typedef the array like so:

```
typedef bool set[128];
```

So you can access it directly:

```
set s = { false };
s[1] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a set, not an array. So, it can't be subscripted. You should access the Array inside the set.

```
temp.Arr[itemp] = true;
```

Comment: thank you so much! the problem was that simple to solve XD